# Java outputStream not working

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a simple setup where I want to write to a file called file.txt. However, when I run the code, nothing is written to the file.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    outputStream.println("Hello World!");
}
}
```

What is the problem here? I cant seem to figure it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You aren't closing the `PrintWriter`. You could fix that by using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement,

```
try (outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));) {
  outputStream.println("Hello World!");  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

or a [`finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

```
try {
  outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
  outputStream.println("Hello World!");  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found");
  System.exit(0);
} finally {
  outputStream.close();
}
```